# Help identifying a strange device in an SMPS PSU

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

[image]
I had 4 SMPS PSUs blow up after PGE power resumption on our fileservers.
I opened it and found this strange device. Since its broken I pulled 
it apart and its basically just a straight thick lead (1.5mm or so)
with some white stuff around it and encased in a black plastic cylinder. 
So it would look like a rectifier, except it isn't. The resistance 
across is zero in the working and blown ones. The two vias on the PCB
are for the transformer that was removed. 
One end of the lead is connected to one end of the windings of a
 transfomer in an SMPS PSU.
It has spread this white powder onto surrounding devices. The lead 
itself is not burnt. In fact its unlikely it will melt as its pretty thick.

What purpose would it serve to vaporise the outer coating and leave the
thick lead. Just to be clear this device is a straight continuous lead with the white stuff around and encased in a black plastic cylinder. So there's no resistance across the leads.

I checked another PSU and it also had blown the same way. The working 
one shows a crack on the surface casing, but continues to work.
View of blown device next to transformer

[image]

I found another similar device that is intact. The blue sleeve is loose around the lead:
[image]

Comment: A diode, TVS or varistor. Can you zoom out a bit?

Comment: The device itself is a straight continuous lead, so its a short. Why its shorting one of the coilds of the transformer is a mystery to me.

Comment: Ah! From the location on the PCB, it’s a ferrite bead.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that cylinder is plastic. My guess is that what you have found is actually a ferrite bead: essentially a ferrite bead is a zero turn inductor
(Basically a ferrite bead is a single wire going straight through the center hole of a ferrite cylinder).

By the way there is a way to check what you have. If the cylinder itself is magnetic it’s most likely that it’s a ferrite bead if it’s not magnetic than it’s probably plastic. If that’s the case then I have no idea what you’ve got.

(:

Comment: Hmm.. yes of course,  that sounds plausible, I found another device intact, so I will test the magnetism and report back.

Comment: Mr.Tech, you are right it is magnetic! Though why theres all that white powdery stuff when it got overheated is a mystery to me. But at least now I know its a ferrite bead. Any idea why they get so hot? Is it because of a high frequency high current flow?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Is there a way to determine the replacement ferrite bead spec? I read somewhere the color specifies the type. Besides just basing on the bead size, is wire gauge important?

Comment: Probably too much current.

Comment: To be honest I don’t know much about ferrite beads what I told you is all I know. My only source for ferrite beads are old circuit boards.  (:

Comment: Because currents form closed loops, the zero-turn inductor is actually a one-turn inductor. Every pass through the hole counts as one turn,